# How can I return the required message without the distinct message?

Tags: angularjs

I have a small password form that returns different messages depending on what has been entered, if nothing has been entered the message should just be `"please enter a password"` if the password entered is like the username then the only error message back should be  `"Your password can not be like your username"`. And finally when the pattern doesnt match the user should get a message about the pattern. When I enter nothing and click submit I am getting both the distinct and required messages back, how can I fix this to only show the required message until data has been entered that matches the username?

**HTML:**

```
    <div ng-controller="NewPasswordCtrl" ng-init="init()">

  <form name="npForm" class="col-md-12" role="form" style="padding-top:15px" ng-submit="SubmitPasswordReset(npForm, NewPasswordModel)" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="newPassword" name="newPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" ng-model="NewPasswordModel.Password" ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true}" override-password user="{{NewPasswordModel.Username}}" ng-style="npForm.newPassword.$error.pattern && {'border':'1px solid red'}"
          required>

        <small id="newPasswordHelpBlock0" class="form-text text-danger" ng-if="npForm.newPassword.$error.required && npForm.$submitted">
                                Please enter a password.
                            </small>
        <small id="newPasswordHelpBlock1" class="form-text text-danger" ng-if="npForm.newPassword.$error.pattern && npForm.$submitted">
                                Password is not valid. Password must be at least 8 characters, upper and lower case text, contain at least one number and contain at least one special character.
                            </small>
        <small id="newPasswordHelpBlock2" class="form-text text-danger" ng-if="npForm.newPassword.$error.distinct && npForm.$submitted">
                                Your password can not be like your username.
                            </small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="ml-5">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
    <hr /> model = {{NewPasswordModel}}
  </form>
</div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('NewPasswordCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.NewPasswordModel = {};
  $scope.NewPasswordModel.Password = "";

  $scope.init = function() {
    $scope.NewPasswordModel.Username = 'Tester'
  };

  $scope.SubmitPasswordReset = function (form, model) {
    if (form.$valid) {};
  };
}]);

app.directive('overridePassword', function() {
  var PASSWORD_REGEXP = /(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{7,}/;

  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      var usr = attrs.user;

      //For DOM -> model validation
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(modelValue) {
        var valid = modelValue.includes(usr);
        ctrl.$setValidity('distinct', valid);
        return valid ? modelValue : undefined;
      });

      //For model -> DOM validation
      ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(modelValue) {
        ctrl.$setValidity('distinct', modelValue.includes(usr));
        return modelValue;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/devnsyde/q8v1b4Lj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another && condition to your ngIf directive that checks the length of your password input.

```
ng-if="npForm.newPassword.$error.distinct && npForm.$submitted && NewPasswordModel.Password.length > 0"
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fz2ax53k/)**

Comment: That is a really good idea lol, so simple. I have been trying to do it in the directive.

Comment: @Devnsyde I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I just tested it with entering just the Username and now I am not getting the distinct error message. I am assuming it is something with my directive which is ok because I have a different version that includes my pattern matching that is working fine.Thanks again!